# Subtleties dealing with cross compilation, freestanding libgcc, etc

Tags: c, gcc, x86, osdev, freestanding

I have a few questions about https://wiki.osdev.org/Meaty_Skeleton, which says:

> The GCC documentation explicitly states that libgcc requires the
>   freestanding environment to supply the `memcmp`, `memcpy`, `memmove`, and
>   `memset` functions, as well as `abort` on some platforms. We will satisfy
>   this requirement by creating a special kernel C library (libk) that
>   contains the parts of the user-space libc that are *freestanding*
>   (doesn't require any kernel features) as opposed to hosted libc
>   features that need to do system calls

Alright, I understand that `libgcc` is a 'private library' that is used by gcc, i.e. It has significance only during the compilation process, when gcc is in use, kind of like a helper for gcc. Is this right? I understand that the machine I run gcc on is called the build machine, and the host machine is my own OS. What is the freestanding environment specified here? Since gcc runs on the build machine, libgcc must use the build machine libgcc I guess? Where does freestanding come into the picture?

Also, what is the libk? I think that I really don't understand freestanding and hosted environments yet :(

Comment: `libk` is just a name that the authors of this tutorial chose for the library they're going to create, to provide those ISO C functions that libgcc depends on.

Comment: @PeterCordes What is the freestanding environment here? My host system (the os I'm building)?

Comment: It's the one that stands on its own, not hosted by an OS.  i.e. it's the kernel you're developing.  There are several clues to that from context in that paragraph, like the last sentence basically defines it: *freestanding (doesn't require any kernel features)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[libgcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html)**

This library must be linked in some cases when you compile with GCC. Because GCC produces calls to functions in this library, if the target architecture doesn't support a specific feature.

For example, if you use 64-Bit arithmetic in your kernel and you want compile for **i386**, then GCC make a call to the specific function which resides in `libgcc`:

```
uint64_t div64(uint64_t dividend, uint64_t divisor)
{
    return (dividend / divisor);
}
```

Here you get an `undefined reference to __udivdi3` error from the linker when you try to link your kernel without `libgcc`. On the other side, `libgcc` also make calls to standard C library functions. So these specific functions must be implemented.

Here is another IMHO good [explanation](http://cs107e.github.io/guides/gcc/). It's called bare-metal programming here for the ARM architecture, but also valid for x86.